# Changing the avatar in Avateering sample (Kinect Developer Toolkit v1.7.0)

Tags: kinect, skinning, maya, kinect.toolbox

I've been trying to make a virtual dressing room, but am not able to change the avatar of the Avateering sample. I even tried with minor changes in the mesh of the Avatar in Autodesk Maya, but couldn't go through. When I run the code with this new Avatar, no Avatar gets displayed on the screen.

I've  changed the Content Processor to `SkinnedModelProcessor` as well, as mentioned in a post I searched on the web.

I also followed the following blog post but again some random part of the new Avatar show up in the game environment, at an incorrect location.

http://mopred.blogspot.in/2012/11/changing-avateering-avatar-in-kinect.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to do a virtual dressing room, I too struggled with the same problem. But finally I decided to skip boned model animating and went to normal matrix rotations and movements to 3D non flexible cloths. If you want I can provide help on those. Also I found a link which describe [switching the avatar in example](http://mopred.blogspot.com/2012/11/changing-avateering-avatar-in-kinect.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help Shamitha! I was finally able to do the boned model animation right. The link you provided is the one I've put up in the question. I used the information there for the model's inversion problem.